# Why "ID = 0" when I try to insert in database while the field is primary key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to insert (create) a book in the `BookInfo` table in database but I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Book_Categories_BookInfo_BookID". The conflict occurred in database "MyBookShopDB", table "dbo.BookInfo", column 'BookID'.

I have `BookInfo` and `Category` with a many-to-many relationship.

And I am using a view model to do the job. I think the problem is that when I trace my `Create` action method, then I see that the `BookID` is "0"

But `BookID` is defined as an auto-increment primary key and I do not know why it is still "0" when I try to create or insert a book into the database....

Does anyone know what should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks!

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(BooksCreateViewModel ViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Book book = new Book()
                        {
                            ISBN = ViewModel.ISBN,
                            Stock = ViewModel.Stock,
                            Price = ViewModel.Price,
                            Title = ViewModel.Title,
                        };

        await _context.Books.AddAsync(book);
    }
}
```

Here is the BookInfo Class:

```
  [Table("BookInfo")]
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Migration class:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "BookInfo",
            columns: table => new
            {
                BookID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Summary = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Price = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Stock = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            },
```

SQL

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Book_Categories] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Book_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookID] ASC,[CategoryID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: What is the C# class for `Book` look like? Did you in fact **define** the `ID` field to be auto-incremented on the database side?? What database system are you using, btw??

Comment: Yes i did!

 [Table("BookInfo")]
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookID { get; set; }

I am using SQL 2017

Comment: @Mustafa Please add the full code you have to your question, not just fractions of it.

Comment: I have changed  the name  of the table to "BookInfo" by on attribute:.[Table("BookInfo")]

Comment: I have tried and edited my post and added more about SQL database in my post! @Gret Arnold

Comment: Look at the error...it sure looks like a Foreign Key constraint error.

Comment: Make sure youve done an update-database at Package Manager Console...and update the OP with you category migration.

Comment: I know that its about Foreign Key error! I wonder if someone can help to solve it!

Comment: I have done update-database many times!

Comment: OK...sorry for asking. But by the looks of that FK_name you have got some tables mixed up. Do you have a table named Book and another named BookInfo? @GertArnold eluded to this earlier "Which means that you're not showing the actual running code."

Comment: No problem! :)  No its same table that I have changed name by a  attribute:.[Table("BookInfo")] It is the actual running code!

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say," I do not know why it is still NULL when I try to create or insert a book into the database...." Yes it will be null...The database will do the assigning and incrementing. Are you saying its null in the database?

Comment: It never be saved in database because the "BookID" is a Primary Key and must a value before saving in database! When I try to trace my code then the "BookID"s value is = 0

Comment: No...thats not how it works. When a database field is autoincrement...the database creates the identity. This code:".Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")," means start at 1 and increase by 1. Notice how the Create route is missing BookId?

Answer (score 2):

In the Book Entity have you added a decorator to Book.ID to inform Entity Framework to allow the Server to assign the value?

Something like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book() { }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Stock { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
}
```

[Information on Entity Framework Core Database Annotation](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute)

Comment: This is the Migration class:


migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "BookInfo",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    BookID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),

Comment: Based on the BookInfo Model class, I would swap the decorator on int BookID from [key] to [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key] to let EF know to allow the server to assign the ID Value.

Comment: In fact this looks more like a comment than an answer. Also, if `Book` has a property `BookID` the attribute isn't strictly necessary. EF would infer it as the primary key, db-generated.

Comment: Not sure that EF would infer it properly, but when I ran into an extremely similar issue with a SQL Server Identity, adding the DatabaseGenerated Decorator to the Entity Class it fixed the issue and allowed the server to assign the values as expected.

Comment: EF will take `ID` as PK, identity. No doubt. This PK doesn't seem to be relevant here, but OP isn't capable of analyzing the issue sufficiently.